# blank page entering the app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set my application to works with 2 layouts (one without sidebars, one with 2 sidebars), this is my solution:

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: "/",
                abstract:true,
                templateUrl: "/layouts/main.html"
            })
            .state('sidebars', {
                url: "/",
                abstract:true,
                templateUrl: "/layouts/two-sidebar.html"
            })
            .state('home', {
                parent:'main',
                templateUrl: "/partials/home.html"
            })
            .state('about', {
                url: "about",
                parent:'sidebars',
                templateUrl: "/partials/about.html"
            })
```

main.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view class="view"/>
</div>
```

two-sidebar.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">leftcontent</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div ui-view class="view"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">rightcontent</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure there are better solutions, but with this all works fine.
The only problem is when I visit the root page `/#/` the first time I get a blank page, when I click on `home` the url is the same but it works fine.

To be more clear, here the plunker, to see the problem you have to open it in an external windows (the blue button in the preview window): http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4cZM69hn0lutYEYjmxH?p=preview

**EDIT**: It looks like the main problem was the missing *empty* url

```
.state('home', {
                url:"",
                parent:'main',
                templateUrl: "/partials/home.html"
            })
```

Comment: what are you wanting as child states? Not really clear what your intentions are here. Suggest reading the nested states section of the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined two states bound to the same URL (`/`).

According to UI Router's design, only one state should be bound to a URL.

If you *want* to have two states with the same URL, make the second one the child state and let it have nothing in it's URL prop like so:

```
.state('main', {
            url: "/",
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: "/layouts/main.html"
        })
        .state('main.sidebars', {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: "/layouts/two-sidebar.html"
        })
```

Comment: I edited the question with what it looks like a solution, not sure why my app works with 2 states pointing to  `url:"/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this,

```
.state('main', {
            url: "/",
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: "/layouts/main.html"
        })
.state('sidebars', {
            url: "/something",
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: "/layouts/two-sidebar.html"
        })
```

Comment: I updated the plunker, as you can see this not solves.